# How should one weight elemental damage compared to other damage stats?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the new system of elemental damage, I was wondering when given the choice (for a reroll at the Mystic) if I should pick elemental damage over another historical damage stats (like Crit Chance or Crit Damage) ? How does elemental damage affect my overall DPS compared to those stats ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the 2.0.1 update came out, elemental damage has been the bread and butter of every class. Every skill in the game was given an elemental type (Fire, Poison, Holy, Physical etc.) in order to allow player to benefit from the new items affixes +X% to *element* damage

**Let's take a quick example :**

You are playing Wizard with the skill [Ray of Frost](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/ray-of-frost). As you can see, the skill deals 510% weapon damage. Let's assume you have a legendary bracer that add 20% damage to cold skills, Ray of Frost now deals *510% x 1.2 = 612%*.

Now imagine you have a [Stone of Jordan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stone-of-jordan) equipped aswell giving you another source of 15% cold skill damage. Since elemental damage is additive your total bonus to cold skills is simply the sum of all your bonuses. It will be calculated as follow :

*Total bonus =  1+ 0.2 (bracer) + 0.15 (Stone of Jordan) = 1.35*. Ray of Frost will now deal *510% x 1.35 = 688,5% weapon damage.*

As you can see, stacking %elemental damage is immensely powerfull and provide a more stable DPS than Crit Hit Chance (CHC). The CHC and Crit Hit Damage (CHD) are complementary and rely on each other to be efficient (you need a good balance between both in order to output a good DPS). A normal character will usually get about 9.23% total damage increase from the 6% Critical Hit Chance stat (because it depends on the CHD number and the attack speed for more or less Crit Hit). If, instead of that stat, you went with 15% *element* damage you would be getting a huge 15% total damage increase to all your *element* skills.

What the 2.0.1 has brought with this stat is sustained damage. You don't have to rely much on the 50% CHC and 400% CHD to deals big damage but instead your damage are better constantly. Of course a well end geared Character will benefit from both  elemental damange and the couple CHC/CHD. But at low level or when your gear is not finished, I would advise to go for elemental damage when given the choice.

Comment: While I agree that its more stable, but keep in mind the other side of the equation, your 688.5% is multiplied by your weapon damage, which IS affected by things like CHC and CHD, so if that weapon damage drops too small, then having a huge elemental multiplier is useless.  In general its well recommended to go balanced between all the damage modifiers (wepaon damage, skill boost, elemental boost, elite damage bonus) etc for maximum benefit.

Comment: @z- What do you mean CHC and CHD affect weapon damage ? Don't you mean sheet DPS ? Because for me weapon damage is calculated from the base damage of the weapon (differ if it's a sword, a staff, a 2 handed crossbow etc.), the elemental/black damage bonus (like +993-1100 fire damage) and the potential 2 affixes : +x% damage or +% attack speed. I don't think CHC or CHD affect your *weapon* damage in any way.

Comment: @z- The damage is calculated in this order (not going into much detail but you'll get the idea) : A random number is picked in the damage range of your weapon > Your main attribute boost this number(100 int = +100% damage if you are Wizard) > Then you get a boost from the skill (510% with Ray of frost), that nubmber can be upgraded with the "+x% damage to skill" affixe > then you get the boost from elemental bonus damage on your gear > that final number can crit for your CHD value if the crit success. Refer to this post http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/7004456313 for more detailled figur

Comment: what you say makes sense, but I tend to lump the chd/cc calculations in before it hits the skill % boosts and treat it as 'weapon damage', either way its fine since its all multiplicative anyway so you want to maintain parity between all the damage sources.

Comment: If I have an item which gives "+15% cold skills" and reports -6% damage as a comparison, is it safe to say that the cold skill buff wins (assuming cold-skill usage) since it is not part of the calculation (i.e. has an orange diamond next to the stat)?

Comment: Yes, if you talk about pure DPS, you can allow yoursef to lose 6% dps for 15% skill damage withoit problem. In RoS, sheet dps doesnt matter since most of the damage come from elemental and bonus to a skill. I have done it several time without regret ^_^

Comment: Same here, but I was going on instinct. D3 has a habit of not being completely intuitive

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good summary on how +Elemental Damage works:

The video advises a good way to estimate if a new piece of gear with +Elemental damage is worth equipping:
If you have one piece of gear with +20% fire damage then your damage looks like this:

100 * 1.2 = 120

120 / 100 = 1.2 = 20% Gained

If you are looking at adding another new piece of gear with +20% you can calculate the damage gained by:

100 * 1.4 (+20% on two items) = 140

140 / 120 = 1.166 = 16.6%

Which means adding a second piece of gear that adds +20% fire damage only nets you roughly 16% damage. He goes into much more detail in the video, but this is a nice way to determine if that item you found is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer Elemental Damage over other stats in the most cases, meaning you want to keep a good balance between Elemental DMG and other stats.

Let's assume you deal 1000 DPS, have 20% crit chance and 200% crit dmg and 0% Elemental Damage.

You will result in 1000 + 2/10 x (1000 x 2) DPS = **1400 DPS**

If you now add 20% Elemental DMG (that's the maximum an amulet can provide) you would result in 1400 x 1.2  = **1680 DPS**

If you would instead add 10% crit chance you would be at 1000 + 3/10 x (1000 x 2) DPS = **1600 DPS**

So with this assumption you would end up in a DPS loss if you would go for the crit chance. This is the because because we are assuming we have a default 0 Elemental Damage.

If we now look at the same calculation having 1000 DPS, 20% crit chance, 200% crit dmg BUT 100% Elemental DMG already it looks like this:

We are dealing right now (1000 + 2/10 x (1000 x 2) x 2 = 2800 DPS
Now we get an item which upgrades our Elemental Damage by another 20%, so we have 
(1000 + 2/10 x (1000 x 2)) x 2.2 = **3080 DPS**

If we would reroll the 20% Elemental DMG into 10% crit chance we end up with this:
(1000 + 3/10 x (1000 x 2)) x 2 = **3200 DPS**

As you can see the crit is way better after you got a decent amount of Elemental Damage, same with +Elite DMG, crit hit dmg, strength and attack speed.

**What does this mean?**

You should always have a proper balance between **ALL** stats, and not only the commonly known 0.1% crit chance for 1% crit hit damage. Try to balance, having for example 5 items with crit chance, 5 with hit damage, 5 with elemental damage, 2-3 with elite dmg and a few with +Skill DMG% (your mainly used skill preferably)!

Additionally Moldran calculated around this a bit too and i link you the video he made:

[Moldran about Elemental DMG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3Ev1xDB0XY&hd=1)

Comment: don't forget skill boosts too... you'll want gear that also boosts skill %